# Split in python and strip whitespace

Tags: python, split

I am learning Python, and currently working on reading in a file, splitting the lines and then printing specific elements. I am having trouble splitting multiple times though. The file I am working on has many lines that look like this

```
c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO      100.00  372     0       0       1       372     1       372     0.0       754
```

I am trying to split it, first by tab and newline "/t/n", and then split the elements with |, I have tried .split and .strip and am not having much luck. I figured maybe if I just worked on a single line I could get the idea down, and then modify it into a loop that would access the file

```
blast_out = ("c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO      100.00  372     0       0       1       372     1       372     0.0       754")
fields = blast_out.strip(' \t\r\n').split()
subFields = fields.split("|")
print(fields)
print(subFields)
```

print(fields)

```
['c0_g1_i1|m.1', 'gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO', '100.00', '372', '0', '0', '1', '372', '1', '372', '0.0', '754']
```

print(subFields) generates an error

```
subFields = fields.split('|')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

This is what I did just to try to strip the whitespace and the tabs, then to split on | but it doesn't seem to do anything. Eventually my desired output from this single string would be

```
c0_g1_i1 m.1 Q9HGP0.1 100.0
```

Comment: The `.strip()` is redundant, the `.split()` strips for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of separate strings now. It looks as if the input format encodes *nested* lists; the outer format delimited by whitespace, the inner by `|` characters.

You can split the outer string, then split each resulting element again in a list comprehension:

```
[item.split('|') for item in blast_out.split()]
```

Note that the `str.strip()` is entirely redundant, the `str.split()` call (with no argument or `None` as the first argument) already removes leading and trailing whitespace.

If you expected a flat list, you'd add another loop to the comprehension:

```
[value for item in blast_out.split() for value in item.split('|')]
```

The former would be preferable if the number of items in the inner lists is variable; it is easier to find the first or last element of a nested list than to figure out in a flat list where each whitespace-delimited section starts or ends.

Your final values for your given example then can be extracted with one of the two following expressions, depending on which variant you picked:

```
(result[0][0], result[0][1], result[1][3], result[2][0])
```

or

```
(result[0], result[1], result[5], result[7])
```

Demo:

```
>>> blast_out = "c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO      100.00  372     0       0       1       372     1       372     0.0       754"
>>> [item.split('|') for item in blast_out.split()]
[['c0_g1_i1', 'm.1'], ['gi', '74665200', 'sp', 'Q9HGP0.1', 'PVG4_SCHPO'], ['100.00'], ['372'], ['0'], ['0'], ['1'], ['372'], ['1'], ['372'], ['0.0'], ['754']]
>>> (_[0][0], _[0][1], _[1][3], _[2][0])
('c0_g1_i1', 'm.1', 'Q9HGP0.1', '100.00')
>>> [value for item in blast_out.split() for value in item.split('|')]
['c0_g1_i1', 'm.1', 'gi', '74665200', 'sp', 'Q9HGP0.1', 'PVG4_SCHPO', '100.00', '372', '0', '0', '1', '372', '1', '372', '0.0', '754']
>>> (_[0], _[1], _[5], _[7])
('c0_g1_i1', 'm.1', 'Q9HGP0.1', '100.00')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You do a great job explaining it here :) This solution works on the single line, but when I try to loop through an input file, I am still having some issues with applying the loop to each line instead of only the first line. `blast_output = open("blast.txt").read()
for line in blast_output:
    fields = blast_output.split()
    subFields = [item.split('|') for item in blast_output.split()]
    print(str(subFields))` It just prints the same line over and over again

Comment: @JamieLeigh: you named the target variable `line` but then split `blast_output`. You don't need to keep the `fields = blast_output.split()` line at all, you don't use it. `subFields = item.split('|') for item in line.split()]` should be enough.

Comment: Oh, thanks! The problem I am having now is that it is converting the entire document into a single line, and printing it once for each line, but I want to iterate through each line individually, I don't know if that is making sense. But is there something wrong with my `for line in blast_output:` loop that I could change so that it will split each line, and let me print out information from each line individually?

Comment: Wait, `blast_output` is not a file, that's a string. You want to use `for line in <open file object>:` here.

Comment: I'm not sure what changes to make, I thought importing the file in would work. I updated the original question with what I am having problems with

Comment: @JamieLeigh: sorry, if you have more problems, you'd have to ask a new question.

Comment: @JamieLeigh: you read the whole file into one big string, looping gives you individual characters. Don't use `.read()`; just use `open()` and then use a `for` loop to loop over the file, that gives you each individual line.